# Function that prints reverse of a string/char array in C

Tags: arrays, string, function, input, reverse

I am rather new to the C language right now and I am trying some practice on my own to help me understand how C works. The only other language I know proficiently is Java. Here is my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char * reverse(char word[]);

const char * reverse(char word[]) {
    char reverse[sizeof(word)];
    int i, j;

    for (i = sizeof(word - 1); i <= 0; i--) {
        for (j = 0; j > sizeof(word - 1); j++) {
            reverse[i] = word[j];
        }
    }
    return reverse;
}

int main() {
    char word[100];

    printf("Enter a word: ");
    scanf("%s", word);

    printf("%s backwards is %s\n", word, reverse(word));

    return 0;
}
```

When the user enters a word, the program successfully prints it out when i store it but when i call the reverse function I made it doesnt return anything. It says on my editor the address of the memory stack is being returned instead and not the string of the array I am trying to create the reverse of in my function. Can anyone offer an explanation please :(

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(word)` is incorrect. When the `word` array is passed to a function, it is passed as a pointer to the first char, so you are taking the size of the pointer (presumably 4 or 8, on 32- or 64-bit machines). Confirm by printing out the size. You need to use `strlen` to get the length of a string.

There are other problems with the code. For instance, you shouldn't need a nested loop to reverse a string. And sizeof(word-1) is even worse than sizeof(word). And a loop that does `i--` but compares `i<=0` is doomed: `i` will just keep getting more negative.

Comment: its ok thanks for taking the time to answer. Like I mentioned before, I am still learning C atm and trying to learn through errors. Thanks for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your `reverse` function. C is very different from Java. It is a lot simpler and has less features.

1. Sizes of arrays and strings don't propagate through parameters like you think. Your `sizeof` will return wrong values.
2. `reverse` is an identifier that is used twice (as function name and local variable).
3. You cannot return variables that are allocated on stack, because this part of stack might be destroyed after the function call returns.
4. You don't need two nested loops to reverse a string and the logic is also wrong.

What you probably look for is the function `strlen` that is available in header `string.h`. It will tell you the length of a string. If you want to solve it your way, you will need to know how to allocate memory for a string (and how to free it).

If you want a function that reverses strings, you can operate directly on the parameter `word`. It is already allocated outside the `reverse` function, so it will not vanish.

If you just want to output the string backwards without really reversing it, you can also output char after char from the end of the string to start by iterating from `strlen(word) - 1` to `0`.

Comment: Ok i saw what you meant about the reverse variable in the reverse function and renamed it as backwards. also used strlen() instead of sizeof. Thank you for answering, i am still learning...

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Changed my `reverse()` function to avoid pointer arithmetic and to allow reuse of `word`.

1. Don't return `const` values from a function; the return value cannot be assigned to, so `const` doesn't make sense. Caveat: due to differences between the C and C++ type system, you *should* return strings as `const char *` if you want the code to also compile as C++.
2. Arrays passed as params always "decay" to a pointer.
3. You can't return a function-local variable, unless you allocate it on the heap using `malloc()`. So we need to create it in `main()` and pass it as a param.
4. Since the args are pointers, with no size info, we need to tell the function the size of the array/string: `sizeof` won't work.
5. To be a valid C string, a pointer to or array of `char` must end with the string termination character `\0`.
6. Must put maximum length in scanf format specifier (`%99s` instead of plain `%s` — leave one space for the string termination character `\0`), otherwise vulnerable to buffer overflow.

---

```c
   #include <stdio.h>  // size_t, scanf(), printf()
   #include <string.h> // strlen()

// 1.         // 2.       // 3.                // 4.
   char *reverse(char *word, char *reversed_word, size_t size);

   char *reverse(char *word, char *reversed_word, size_t size)
   {
           size_t index = 0;

           reversed_word[size] = '\0'; // 5.

           while (size-- > index) {
                   const char temp = word[index];
                   reversed_word[index++] = word[size];
                   reversed_word[size]    = temp;
           }

           return reversed_word;
   }

   int main() {
           char word[100];
           size_t size = 0;

           printf("Enter a word: ");
           scanf("%99s", word); // 6.

           size = strlen(word);

           printf("%s backwards is %s\n", word, reverse(word, word, size));

           return 0;
   }
```